# Filtering filenames

Tags: java, regex, filenames

I am having a lot of problems filtering filenames in Java. I am using the PrimeFaces fileUpload tag, and I need to allow files that can be uploaded if they contain only alphanumeric characters followed by an extension, such as ".txt".  To be specific, before the extension, the name must contain one or more of A-Z, a-z, or 0-9, with no spaces or other characters, followed by the extension ".txt", i.e. there must be one, and only one "." in the name, and that must be at the beginning of the extension.

So far all attempts of filtering names have not worked out properly, if I exclude `.`, then it is also excluded from the extension.  Filename should be of the type: `abcXYZ123.txt`, `aaaccc001.txt`, etc. but not `ab.cd.txt` etc.

I have tried various combinations of `/[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.txt$/`, `/[^\\W_]+\\.txt$/`, `/[\\p{Alnum}]\\.txt$/`, etc., but either they allow some invalid names, or exclude somevalid names.

Some help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Judging from the example in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf) the problem could be in your double backslashes. Have you tried `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+\.txt$/`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with the `$` at the end. I would match that with a caret `^` at the beginning to get

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.txt$
```

Just as `$` means "the end of the line," so `^` means "the start of the line."

[Testing this](http://regexpal.com/) with the regex`^[A-Za-z0-9]+\.txt$`, I get:

**Matches**

- `a.txt`
- `abcXYZ123.txt`
- `aaccc001.txt`

**No matches**

- `a.b.c.txt`
- `ab.cd.txt`
- `.txt`

As a side note, depending on your Regex implementation, alnum may or may not be equal to `[A-Za-z0-9]` – it could contain numerals from other numbering systems (e.g. 六, which is six in Chinese).

Comment: Yes, that now works - many thanks indeed. I forgot that I had to match "^" with "$". I decided not to use Alnum, as that is dependent on the character set, and my application will be moved to a Linux computer, which may or may not support it.  Incidentally, the double backslash is necessary, as a single backslash is an escape character in Java, so that itself has to be escaped.

Comment: @csharp: I'm glad to hear that it worked. If you found this answer helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark on the left hand side.